# Delete item of arraylist in activity with recyclerview and adapter, called by another activity

Tags: android, arraylist, android-activity, android-recyclerview, crud

I'm working on a minimal CRUD application (a phonebook). From my list activity, with an arraylist of  custom objects (with 3 strings: name, phone number, notes), and from my recyclerview adapter, I launch another activity passing item position and the selected object (no startActivityforResults). This activity displays the details of this object and a "delete" button. When pressing this button, I launch the previous activity, passing two parameters: callingActivity name and the item position.
As the list activity can be called from other activities (first of all "MainActivity"), I use a switch....case construct. If I insert arraylist.remove(item position) in this switch... case, the activity method onCreate() immediately restarts with callingActivity = MainActivity.

When I run my app, I pass from mainActivity, ListPhoneBook activity, Details activity and finally return to ListPhoneBook activity.

The log is:

```
AAA: callingActivity = MainActivity 
BBB: callingActivity = DetailsDelete 
AAA: callingActivity = MainActivity
```

If I delete the .remove method, the log will be:

```
AAA: callingActivity = MainActivity 
BBB: callingActivity = DetailsDelete 
CCC: callingActivity = DetailsDelete
```

Why the activity restarts immediately after the remove command?

Please help me. Thank you.

```
public class ListPhoneBook extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String callingActivity;
    private ContactModel currentRow;
    private int itemPosition;

    SharedPreferences preferences;

    private ArrayList<ModelloContatto> myContactList;


    private mioAdapterRubrica adapterRubrica;

    private ContactModel rigaAppoggio;

    //elemente grafici
    private EditText etLisRubInNome, etLisRubImNote;
    private ImageButton ibLisRubCambiaNome, ibLisRubCambiaNote;
    private RecyclerView rvListaPrefRecycler;
    private BottomNavigationView nvListaRubBottomMenu;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_rubrica);
        callingActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("callingActivity");
        Log.d("Log","AAA: callingActivity = " + callingActivity);

        initialization();


        switch (callingActivity) {
            case "MainActivity":
            case "Detail":
                readPreferences();
                break;

            case "DetailsDelete":
                Log.d("Log","BBB: callingActivity = " + callingActivity);
                itemPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("itemPosition",-1);
                myContactList.remove(itemPosition);
                Log.d("Log","CCC: callingActivity = " + callingActivity);
                break;
        }
        showData();
    }

    private void initialization() {
        etLisRubInNome = findViewById(R.id.etLisRubInNome);
        etLisRubImNote = findViewById(R.id.etLisRubImNote);
        ibLisRubCambiaNome = findViewById(R.id.ibLisRubCambiaNome);
        ibLisRubCambiaNote = findViewById(R.id.ibLisRubCambiaNote);
        rvListaPrefRecycler = findViewById(R.id.rvListaPrefRecycler);

        nvListaRubBottomMenu = findViewById(R.id.nvListaRubBottomMenu);
        nvListaRubBottomMenu.setItemIconTintList(null);

        myContactList = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    private void readPreferences() {
        myContactList.add(new ModelloContatto("AAAAAA","123456", "aaaaa"));
        myContactList.add(new ModelloContatto("BBBBB","999999", "bbbbb"));
        myContactList.add(new ModelloContatto("CCCCC","88888", "ccccc"));
        myContactList.add(new ModelloContatto("DDDDD","77777", "ddddd"));
        myContactList.add(new ModelloContatto("EEEEE","666666", "eeeee"));
    }

    private void showData() {
        Collections.sort(myContactList);
        final LinearLayoutManager mioLLM = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvListaPrefRecycler.setLayoutManager(mioLLM);

        adapterRubrica = new mioAdapterRubrica(myContactList, this);
        rvListaPrefRecycler.setAdapter(adapterRubrica);
        rvListaPrefRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
}
```

I tried to manage CRUD operations on arraylist in an activity with recyclerview and adapter, with interactions with other activities for adding, editing, deleting single items.

Comment: Looks like the call to `myContactList.remove()` is probably throwing an exception. Set a breakpoint and see what happens there, or look in the logcat for any exceptions.

Comment: You are right. I got an exception for indexoutofbound. The flow of the class is wrong. Thank you very very very much.